# How do i print a report from my jTable in Java

Tags: java, swing

this is the code I wrote to print from jTbale1.

```
 private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("Report");
    MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Page{0,number, integer");
    try{
       Boolean complite =  jTable1.print(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL, header, footer);
    if(complite){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done Printing...");
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Printing...");
    }
    }catch(java.awt.print.PrinterException e){
        System.err.printf("Cannot print %s%n", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

when the button is clicked this exception pops

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmatched braces in the pattern.
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:508)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:362)
    at bookrecording.Report.jButton5ActionPerformed(Report.java:355)
    at bookrecording.Report.access$700(Report.java:23)
    at bookrecording.Report$8.actionPerformed(Report.java:127)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: `"Page{0,number, integer"` should probably be `"Page{0,number, integer}"`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the Right braces `}` in the 3rd line of your code.

Change `new MessageFormat("Page{0,number, integer")` to `new MessageFormat("Page{0,number, integer}")` and it should solve it.

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("Report");

    MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Page{0,number, integer}"); //Done
    try{
       Boolean complite =  jTable1.print(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL, header, footer);
    if(complite){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done Printing...");
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Printing...");
        }
    }catch(java.awt.print.PrinterException e){
        System.err.printf("Cannot print %s%n", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: If the answer helps you then upvote and Accept the Answer and close the thread.